# How to make lookups fail immediately if something is not found?

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to make `lookup('file')` more strict? I would like it to fail if a file does not exist and don't want to find out when Ansible gets to the task that uses that variable. It seems to me that the expression is only lazily evaluated and `errors='strict'` is already the default, but I want it stricter.

Example:

Non-existing file in some file for variables, e.g `some_role/vars/main.yml`

```
some_var: "{{ lookup('file', 'DOES-NOT-EXIST.txt', errors='strict' ) }}"
```

This does only fail when it is used in a task, e.g. `some_role/tasks/main.yml`

```
- debug:
    msg: "$some_var is '{{ some_var }}'"
```

Are there maybe alternatives to `lookup('file')`? Like a Bash equivalent that has this behavior? E.g.

```
some_var: "{{ $(cat 'DOES-NOT-EXIST.txt') }}"
```

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: No. The jinja2 content of any variable only gets evaluated when the variable is used (and each time it is used). Meanwhile there are modules like `fail` or `assert` you can use to verify some conditions are met before going on with your playbook. The is also the `default` filter to add a default content value if the file does not exist.

Comment: @Zeitounator Damn. But thanks a lot for [assert](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html). It seems that Ansible loads all variables from the roles in playbook beforehand and it's possible to use `assert` in the `pre_tasks` before starting to process any role. And it's possible to test a list of variables at once in a single task. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

just use `ls` it has an returncode > 0 if the file does not exists, together with a shell command it will fail then.

```
- shell: "ls DOES-NOT-EXIST.txt"
```

Comment: Bad approach. Don't use. Use `fail` or `assert`.